# Git-flow reopening a finished feature

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-flow

I am trying to work with [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) and [A Successful Git Branching Model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Ones in a while I work on features and finish the feature with

```
git flow feature finish my-feature
```

While continuing to work I realize that I have something forget to add to `my-feature`

Or sometimes I am working on a different feature and want to add something to `my-feature` again...

What would be the way to do this?
Is there a way to re-open `my-feature` again?
Would I just commit the changes into development?
Or open up another feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the git-flow principle, i think you should

1. Create a **new feature branch** and do the changes. Then merge it back to dev. This is if you are adding a whole new feature.
2. Use the **hotfix branch** method. This is if its a minor tweak.

A feature branch deleted should not be recovered under git-flow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply is hotfix not something you apply on a release?

Comment: hotfix is something that is applied to both the release and the dev. You use that when you have already merged release with master. Otherwise its release branch commiting or new feature branch.